# Where is the 'Build' target defined

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, targets

I am trying to understand MSBuild and the first step is to look at the default project file created for a C# project.
I am trying to locate where the default target - 'Build', is defined. Only the 'Microsoft.CSharp.targets' is imported by default and I can't find the 'Build' task there.
So where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

Guess I found it.

$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets